# How to do a conditional mysql left join based on table in the actual fields using query builder

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, query-builder

When setting up a product I have the option to limit its availability to a customer's country, region, and city. Based on this, I only show the product to relevant customers in the system who match this criterion.

In some cases, I want to set a product to a country/region only and ignore city and I am wondering how best to write this query.

The way I see it, I have two options.

1. If a product is relevant to all cities and regions, simply include them all (a lot of data).
2. If a city/region is not required, simply ignore the statements that limit them.

PRODUCT:

```
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uuid                | binary(16)       | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

MANY TO MANY JOIN TO LOCATION

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| meta_location_id | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

LOCATION

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| iso         | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

QUERY BUILDER CODE

```
$qb = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('product');
$qb->orderBy('product.id', 'ASC');

//If we are limiting by country
if (isset($options['country']) and null !== $options['country']) {
    $qb->andWhere('product.country = :country')
        ->setParameter('country', $options['country']);
}
```

REGIONS/CITIES:

The region option is the customer's current region, this is sent regardless and I have no control over it. Since I am searching in the product table, I need to check if the product region exists or not. If it does then I must limit it against the existing region otherwise ignore it.

CURRENT QUERY:
With this query, if region does not match, then it will not list the product. I would like to change this to a condition where it only applies IF data exists in the product table.

```
   if (isset($options['region']) and null !== $options['region']) {
        $qb->leftJoin('product.regions', 'region');
        ->andWhere(($qb->expr()->in('region', [$options['region']])));
    }
```

I am guessing I need something along the lines of

```
    $qb->add('select', 'CASE WHEN region.id IS NOT NULL then do some query...
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was how I solved this issue.

Instead of doing something complicated like trying to figure out if a join contained data or not. I simply created a dummy row in our meta locations table.

Our join now looks like this:

```php
  if (isset($options['region']) and null !== $options['region']) {
        $qb->leftJoin('product.regions', 'region');
        ->andWhere(($qb->expr()->in('region', [12345, $options['region']])));
  }
```

Where 12345 is the ID to the dummy row.

When setting the product up, in the form drop-down-menu I have an item called "Any" meaning it does not matter which region the customer is living in as any region will do.

So now the join will be valid if any is selected, otherwise, if the region matches an actual region, then it works too.

Well, there we have it, often the simplest solutions are the best!